# Find the supremum and infimum (if exist) of the set $\{\frac{m}{n} + \frac{4n}{m} \mid m,n \in \Bbb N\}$ and $\{x:x^2+x+1>0\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Find the supremum and infimum (if exist) of the set
$S = \{\frac{m}{n} + \frac{4n}{m} \mid m,n \in \Bbb N\}$ and $T = \{x:x^2+x+1>0\}$.

**Attempt:**
First, notice that $S = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x \gt 4\}$.

For the set $S$, by $AM-GM$ inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{m}{n} + \frac{4n}{m} &\ge 2\sqrt{\frac{m}{n} \cdot \frac{4n}{m}} = 2\cdot \sqrt{4} = 2\cdot 2 = 4.
\end{align*}
Thus, $4$ is a lower bound of $S$. We claim that $\inf(S)=4$. Let $m$ be an any lower bound of $S$.
We'll show that $m \le 4$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $m \gt 4$. Let $r$ be an arbitrary rational number such that $4 < r < m$. Then, we have $r \in S$ and $m \gt r$. This is impossible since $m$ is a lower bound of $S$. Hence, $m \le 4$ and therefore, $\inf(S) = 4$.

Next, set $n=1$ and $m \to \infty$. Then, $\frac{m}{n} + \frac{4n}{m} \to \infty$.
Hence, $\sup(s)$ is doesn't exist.

Am I true?

${}$

For the set $T$, notice that $x^2+x+1$ has two distinct complex roots. How to process next?
What if $x$ there is in real set? What if $x$ there is in complex set?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why is $r \in S$? The proof itself looks good, but that step is not clear for me

Comment: I think, its from the definition of $S$ itself. Note that $S=\{4+\frac{m}{n} \} = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x \gt 4 \}$. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I dont see that :D Can you please prove that?^^

Comment: What about the infimum and supremum of $T$?

Comment: Bring the quadratic formula into the form $a(x-b)^2+d$ and look at the minimum and maximum of that function

Comment: @user795084 Not quite, because $m,n\in N$ is a condition of $S$. For example, $4+\sqrt 2$ is in your set, but not $S$.

Comment: The proof about $4$ being the infimum is wrong: why should $S$ contain any rational number between $4$ and $\inf S$? More simply, try with $m=2$ and $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you showed that $4$ is a lower bound, all that needs to be demonstrated is that the lower bound is attained for some $m, n \in \mathbb N$ in order for $\inf S = 4$.  This is easily accomplished since AM-GM implies that equality is attained when $$\frac{m}{n} = \frac{4n}{m},$$ or $m = 2n$.  So $(m,n) = (2,1)$ gives the desired lower bound, hence this must be the greatest lower bound.

For $x^2 + x + 1$, simply complete the square.  $$x^2 + x + 1 = (x+1/2)^2 + 3/4 \ge 3/4,$$ and so all real numbers satisfy the condition $x^2 + x + 1 > 0$.  Thus I suspect you intended to write instead $$T = \{x^2 + x + 1 : x \in \mathbb R\},$$ in which case $\inf T = 3/4$ and $\sup T = \infty$.

Comment: Does it true that $\sup(T)=\infty$? I mean, why not write $\sup(T)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: Why not $\inf T = -\infty$ and $\sup T = \infty$, since $T$ is definitely equal to $\Bbb R$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You try to conclude that $\inf S=4$ by a wrong argument.

Using $m$ to denote $\inf S$ is confusing, so I'll use $\inf S$. You claim that if $r$ is any rational number such that $4<r<\inf S$, then $r\in S$.

This is to be *proved*, not simply stated (and I think it's even false, because no rational number with even numerator and odd denominator can be written in the form $\frac{m^2+4n^2}{mn}$).

The infimum is actually a minimum, because choosing $m=2$ and $n=1$ you have
$$
\frac{m}{n}+\frac{4n}{m}=\frac{2}{1}+\frac{4}{2}=4
$$

The part about the supremum is correct, but I'd avoid limits: if you fix any $K$, choose a natural number $m$ such that $m>K$. Then
$$
K<\frac{m}{1}+\frac{4\cdot1}{m}\in S
$$
and so $S$ is not upper bounded.

Comment: How can $K \in S$ implies that $S$ is not upper bounded?

Comment: @user795084 Did I say that $K\in S$? I wrote that $K$ is *less* than some element in $S$.

Comment: Oh, my bad Sir. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Sir, what about $T$ ?

Comment: @user795084 $T=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But, for all real $x$, $x^2+x+1>0$, then $T=\Bbb R$ and so $\inf T = -\infty$ and $\sup T = \infty$.

Comment: Nah, I think also like that. And so, is my answer correct?

Comment: @user795084 Inequalities don't make sense in the complex field.

Comment: Sorry? I still confuse.

Comment: Since $T = \Bbb R$, can't we conclude that $T = (-\infty, \infty)$ ?